# How does one properly assign temporary Bash variables on a per-command basis?

Tags: bash, scope, ifs

Bash seems to behave unpredictably in regards to temporary, per-command variable assignment, specifically with `IFS`.

I often assign `IFS` to a temporary value in conjunction with the `read` command. I would like to use the same mechanic to tailor output, but currently resort to a function or subshell to contain the variable assignment.

```sh
$ while IFS=, read -a A; do
>   echo "${A[@]:1:2}"                # control (undesirable)
> done <<< alpha,bravo,charlie
bravo charlie

$ while IFS=, read -a A; do
>   IFS=, echo "${A[*]:1:2}"          # desired solution (failure)
> done <<< alpha,bravo,charlie
bravo charlie

$ perlJoin(){ local IFS="$1"; shift; echo "$*"; }
$ while IFS=, read -a A; do
>   perlJoin , "${A[@]:1:2}"          # function with local variable (success)
> done <<< alpha,bravo,charlie
bravo,charlie

$ while IFS=, read -a A; do
>   (IFS=,; echo "${A[*]:1:2}")       # assignment within subshell (success)
> done <<< alpha,bravo,charlie
bravo,charlie
```

If the second assignment in the following block does not affect the environment of the command, and it does not generate an error, then what is it for?

```
$ foo=bar
$ foo=qux echo $foo
bar
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$ foo=bar
$ foo=qux echo $foo
bar
```

This is a common bash gotcha -- and https://www.shellcheck.net/ catches it:

```
foo=qux echo $foo
^-- SC2097: This assignment is only seen by the forked process.
             ^-- SC2098: This expansion will not see the mentioned assignment.
```

The issue is that the first `foo=bar` is setting a bash variable, not an environment variable. Then, the inline `foo=qux` syntax is used to set an environment variable for `echo` -- however `echo` never actually looks at that variable. Instead `$foo` gets recognized as a bash variable and replaced with `bar`.

So back to your main question, you were basically there with your final attempt using the subshell -- except that you don't actually need the subshell:

```
while IFS=, read -a A; do
  IFS=,; echo "${A[*]:1:2}"
done <<< alpha,bravo,charlie
```

outputs:

```
bravo,charlie
```

For completeness, here's a final example that reads in multiple lines and uses a different output separator to demonstrate that the different IFS assignments aren't stomping on each other:

```
while IFS=, read -a A; do
  IFS=:; echo "${A[*]:1:2}"
done < <(echo -e 'alpha,bravo,charlie\nfoo,bar,baz')
```

outputs:

```
bravo:charlie
bar:baz
```

Comment: Doesn't your solution leave the modified IFS in the environment? 

Since `IFS` is not expanded in `IFS=, echo "${Foo[*]}"`, shouldn't echo see the modified value?

Comment: @vintnes Yes, this changes `IFS` for the rest of a script. An alternative is, for example, `printf '%s\n' "$(IFS=,; echo "${A[*]:1:2}")`, which changes it only in the command subsitution.

Comment: I now understand that all of these expansions occur before `echo` reads its arguments.

Comment: It's not really about shell var versus env var: it's just the order things happen.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is a bit simpler than the other answers are presenting:

```
$ foo=bar
$ foo=qux echo $foo
bar
```

We see "bar" because the shell expands `$foo` **before** setting `foo=qux`

[Simple Command Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion) -- there's a lot to get through here, so bear with me...

> When a simple command is executed, the shell performs the following expansions, assignments, and redirections, from left to right.
>
> 1. The words that the parser has marked as **variable assignments** (those preceding the command name) and redirections **are saved for later processing**.
> 2. The words that are not variable assignments or redirections are **expanded** (see [Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions)). If any words remain after expansion, the first word is taken to be the name of the command and the remaining words are the arguments.
> 3. Redirections are performed as described above (see Redirections).
> 4. The text after the ‘=’ in each variable assignment undergoes tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal before being assigned to the variable.
>
> If no command name results, the variable assignments affect the current shell environment. **Otherwise, the variables are added to the environment of the executed command and do not affect the current shell environment**. If any of the assignments attempts to assign a value to a readonly variable, an error occurs, and the command exits with a non-zero status.
>
> If no command name results, redirections are performed, but do not affect the current shell environment. A redirection error causes the command to exit with a non-zero status.
>
> **If there is a command name left after expansion, execution proceeds** as described below. Otherwise, the command exits. If one of the expansions contained a command substitution, the exit status of the command is the exit status of the last command substitution performed. If there were no command substitutions, the command exits with a status of zero.

So:

- the shell sees `foo=qux` and saves that for later
- the shell sees `$foo` and expands it to "bar"
- then we now have: `foo=qux echo bar`

Once you really understand the order that bash does things, a lot of the mystery goes away.

Comment: Yeah I got there. `foo=qux eval 'echo $foo'` returns `qux`

Comment: except for IFS this doesn't work.  which is exactly the question.

Comment: @SusanneOberhauser I don't understand your comment. Are you addressing me or vintnes? "Otherwise, the variables are added to the environment of the executed command and do not affect the current shell environment" -- that means `IFS= read line` only changes IFS for the duration of the read command.

Comment: changing IFS for `read ...` works because read looks at IFS.  changing IFS ahead of the echo does not work as intended because the shell expands the `echo ...` command before it updates IFS.  I've provided a top level solution "response" for the echo part (using local variables)

Comment: Not quite right. There's nothing special about IFS: bash works the same way for any variable or any command. "the shell expands the echo ... command" -- more precisely, the shell  performs [its series of expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) and then applies the saved variables and then executes the echo command. I'm not trying to be annoying, but it's important to be extremely precise to fully grok bash's rules.

Comment: I think we're talking past each other somehow :-)  your description of the problem is point on:  first the shell does it's expansions including word splitting, to build a sequence of IFS-separated things.: optional temporary environment changes for this next command, then the next command, and then it's arguments, all IFS-separated.  that's what you said, too, I should have been clearer on that, and that yes, you describe that.  Now if you look at my top level answer you'll see that I provide a clean _solution_ how to deal with that, _without_ fork, in bash.  that's all. have a grand day.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: the effects of changing `IFS` are complex and hard to understand, and best avoided except for a few well-defined idioms (`IFS=, read ...` is one of the idioms I consider ok).

Long answer: There are a couple of things you need to keep in mind in order to understand the results you're seeing from changes to `IFS`:

- Using `IFS=something` as a prefix to a command changes `IFS` *only for that one command's execution*. In particular, it does not affect how the shell parses the arguments to be passed to that command; that's controlled by the shell's value of `IFS`, not the one used for the command's execution.
- Some commands pay attention to the value of `IFS` they're executed with (e.g. `read`), but others don't (e.g. `echo`).

Given the above, `IFS=, read -a A` does what you'd expect, it splits its input on ",":

```
$ IFS=, read -a A <<<"alpha,bravo,charlie"
$ declare -p A
declare -a A='([0]="alpha" [1]="bravo" [2]="charlie")'
```

But `echo` pays no attention; it always puts spaces between the arguments it's passed, so using `IFS=something` as a prefix to it has no effect at all:

```
$ echo alpha bravo
alpha bravo
$ IFS=, echo alpha bravo
alpha bravo
```

So when you use `IFS=, echo "${A[*]:1:2}"`, it's equivalent to just `echo "${A[*]:1:2}"`, and since the shell's definition of `IFS` starts with space, it puts the elements of `A` together with spaces between them. So it's equivalent to running `IFS=, echo "alpha bravo"`.

On the other hand, `IFS=,; echo "${A[*]:1:2}"` changes the shell's definition of `IFS`, so it does affect how the shell puts the elements together, so it comes out equivalent to `IFS=, echo "alpha,bravo"`. Unfortunately, it also affects everything else from that point on so you either have to isolate it to a subshell or set it back to normal afterward.

Just for completeness, here are a couple of other versions that don't work:

```
$ IFS=,; echo "${A[@]:1:2}"
bravo charlie
```

In this case, the `[@]` tells the shell to treat each element of the array as a separate argument, so it's left to `echo` to merge them, and it ignores `IFS` and always uses spaces.

```
$ IFS=,; echo "${A[@]:1:2}"
bravo charlie
```

So how about this:

```
$ IFS=,; echo ${A[*]:1:2}
bravo charlie
```

In this case, the `[*]` tells the shell to mash all elements together with the first character of `IFS` between them, giving `bravo,charlie`. But it's not in double-quotes, so the shell immediately re-splits it on ",", splitting it back into separate arguments again (and then `echo` joins them with spaces as always).

If you want to change the shell's definition of `IFS` without having to isolate it to a subshell, there are a few options to change it and set it back afterward. In bash, you can set it back to normal like this:

```
$ IFS=,
$ while read -a A; do    # Note: IFS change not needed here; it's already changed
> echo "${A[*]:1:2}"
> done <<<alpha,bravo,charlie
bravo,charlie
$ IFS=$' \t\n'
```

But the `$'...'` syntax isn't available in all shells; if you need portability it's best to use literal characters:

```
IFS=' 
'        # You can't see it, but there's a literal space and tab after the first '
```

Some people prefer to use `unset IFS`, which just forces the shell to its default behavior, which is pretty much the same as with `IFS` defined in the normal way.

...but if `IFS` had been changed in some larger context, and you don't want to mess that up, you need to save it and then set it back. If it's been changed normally, this'll work:

```
saveIFS=$IFS
...
IFS=$saveIFS
```

...but if someone thought it was a good idea to use `unset IFS`, this will define it as blank, giving weird results. So you can use this approach or the `unset` approach, but not both. If you want to make this robust against the `unset` conflict, you can use something like this in bash:

```
saveIFS=${IFS:-$' \t\n'}
```

...or for portability, leave off the `$' '` and use literal space+tab+newline:

```
saveIFS=${IFS:- 
}                # Again, there's an invisible space and tab at the end of the first line
```

All in all, it's a lot of mess full of traps for the unwary. I recommend avoiding it whenever possible.

Comment: There's nothing special about `read` or `echo`. Those are just builtin commands. The difference is that there's a `$var` in the echo command that gets expanded first.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a shell function, which *locally* sets IFS, like so:

```
$ function ifsdo {
    # set -x
    local IFS="$1"
    local CMD="$2"
    shift 2
    "$CMD" "$*"
}
$ ifsdo , echo foo bar baz
foo,bar,baz
$ echo "ah,blah e,spah njol" | {
    # note: in-line environment variables are local to that one call anyhow:
    IFS=, read -a XXX
    # IFS is back to what it was before
    ifsdo : echo "${XXX[@]}"
}
```